# How to use Unix based line separators in windows 10 using pycharm

Tags: python, unix, path, pycharm, windows-10

I am running a code of UBUNTU in windows 10 in **pycharm2021**. I am facing an issue in line separators

```
:express(warning): Filename uses Windows-style path: C:\Users\Desktop\data\gui\colour_palette.png
:express(warning): expected Unix-style path: /c/Users/Desktop/data/gui/colour_palette.png
```

I tried changing the line separators by using this link
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html

but it didn't work

Comment: Just  use / for ubuntu and // or \ for windows
I suggest u to dont use paths like that, use relatives paths, with os library and u will ve not problems like that

Comment: @LuisBote: are you sure? I think you are meaning / for Ubuntu or \\ or / for Window. In any case, Ubuntu has different convention where to put files, and your code works only on some Windows with a specific configuration/language.

Comment: If its looking about absolute paths should use something like :
import os
directory_path = os.getcwd()